# QML Image is Loaded From Source After a LONG Delay

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtnetwork, qqmlapplicationengine

I am developing an Qt Quick Application where I am serving "main.qml" file over network:

```
QQuickView vv;
vv.engine()->setNetworkAccessManagerFactory(new MyFactory());
vv.setSource(QUrl("http://192.168.1.101/main.qml"));
vv.showFullScreen();
```

main.qml file is :

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Image
{
    id :pencere
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    source: "back.png"
}
```

I created file server using [HFS](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/?f=ss) tool.

I am running my application,it fetches qml file from server.Application starts with a white screen,waiting for a long time than loads image and shows it.As the output shows,it requests for image file very long time after main.qml is requested :

[image]

Why it requests for image **1 MINUTES** later than qml file? How to reduce that duration?

*This is happening too,if I set an image on the internet.I am sure that there is no problem about HFS.*

Comment: Think about it -- how would your application possibly know that it needed to download that image file until *after* it had downloaded the QML file that requested the image?

Comment: I am smart enough to know that. Is not 1 minutes long to find image to download in qml and download it ?

Comment: Add debug output for `Image.status` and compare that to your server's log. Usually loading images from the Internet takes milliseconds so I think the problem is on your machine. Maybe DNS lookup or firewall.

Comment: It's interesting that the image starts to load EXACTLY one minute after the QML has finished loading, as if there is a time-out involved.

Comment: @Mark And if I have more than one image, the request starts 1 minute later than QML but downloads all the images in a second.